# Make javascript open on page load instead of on link click

Tags: javascript, onload

I have a script that opens a popunder when any link is clicked. How can I change this to open the popunder when the page loads. Below is the script.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var puURL = 'http://www.example.com';
  var puTS = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
  console.log('T.'+localStorage.puTS+'/'+puTS);
  if (typeof localStorage.puTS == 'undefined' || parseInt(localStorage.puTS) <= (puTS - 180)) {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
      links[i].onclick = function (e) {
        var puHref = this.getAttribute("href");
          var puTarget = this.getAttribute("target");
          if (puHref !== '#' && puHref !== 'javascript:void(0)') {
          e.preventDefault();    
          if (puTarget == '_blank') {
            window.open(window.location.href);
          }
          window.open(puHref);
          window.location.href = puURL;
          localStorage.puTS = puTS;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, currently you're adding click handlers for all the target elements:

```
for(var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
  links[i].onclick = function (e) { // <--- here
    var puHref = this.getAttribute("href");
    var puTarget = this.getAttribute("target");
    if (puHref !== '#' && puHref !== 'javascript:void(0)') {
      e.preventDefault();    
      if (puTarget == '_blank') {
        window.open(window.location.href);
      }
      window.open(puHref);
      window.location.href = puURL;
      localStorage.puTS = puTS;
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't want to add click handlers but just want to invoke the logic within them right away, just put that logic in the loop without the click handler:

```
for(var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
  var puHref = this.getAttribute("href");
  var puTarget = this.getAttribute("target");
  if (puHref !== '#' && puHref !== 'javascript:void(0)') {
    if (puTarget == '_blank') {
      window.open(window.location.href);
    }
    window.open(puHref);
    window.location.href = puURL;
    localStorage.puTS = puTS;
  }
}
```

Of course, if this logic includes opening a new page or redirecting the user then that's going to happen immediately upon page load...

Comment: Thanks for the response David. I made the changes that you suggested but the popunder still only occurs when clicking a link. I need it to occur only on page load.

Comment: @RichardWise: Can you update the question to include a runnable example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do that here. The .js file is located at https://www.karaoke-software.net/vogone.js

Comment: @RichardWise: Failing that, you could at worst link to an off-site live demonstration.  Ideally all relevant code should be in the question.  For HTML/CSS/JavaScript issues, [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) are the best way to demonstrate the problem in the question.

Comment: I could learn javascript and figure it out on my own in the time it would take me to learn how to post here. Sorry to waste your time.